# German long-term work visa: work contract starting earlier than the visa interview date. Is that a problem?

Tags: working-visas, blue-card

I have received a job offer from a company in Germany. The work contract states that the job starts in early August. However, the earliest date I can secure for my visa application interview is mid-August.

Is this a problem? I asked the company and they are fine with me working from home (from my home country for a couple of months) until I get my German long-term visa and can move to Germany.

However, since the contract's starting date is earlier than the date of my visa interview (and hence I can't make it to Germany on that time) would that create a problem during the visa interview?